# If a creditor refuses to accept payment for a debt, is the debt extinguished?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, debt

JURISDICTION: New Hampshire, United States

If a creditor refuses to accept payment for a debt, is the debt extinguished?

I know this sounds bizarre, but some companies are no longer accepting payment for debts or other obligations unless they meet some criteria.

For example, recently I had a vendor refuse a check to pay for goods because there was a company name on the check and the goods had been purchased under the personal name of the agent who bought the goods, not under the company name. Crazy.

Anyway, from a legal point of view the check was good and was presented to pay for the goods and the vendor's refusal of the check essentially constitutes refusal to accept payment. So, what happens now? Should I consider the debt to be extinguished? Do I need to sue them to extinguish the debt??? What the heck, if they don't accept my check, I don't see how they can keep insisting I owe them money. There was no agreement I ever signed whereby I promised to pay them only out of certain bank accounts or whatever.

What is the law or UCC on this?

Comment: Without writing a full answer, the legal buzz word here that describes the conduct in the question is "tender of payment".

Comment: See this UCC provision. https://law.justia.com/codes/new-hampshire/2016/title-xxxiv-a/chapter-382-a/section-382-a-3-603 and this one https://casetext.com/statute/new-hampshire-revised-statutes/title-34-a-uniform-commercial-code/chapter-382-a-uniform-commercial-code/article-2-sales/part-5-performance/section-382-a2-511-tender-of-payment-by-buyer-payment-by-check

Comment: From your description, you aren't a party to the contract so you don't have any obligation to the vendor, instead a third part has an obligation to the vendor, and you have an obligation to the third party. Clarify.

Comment: @user6726 This is not a question about who owes whom to what. This is question about whether a debt is extinquished if the vendor refuses payment. For example, let's say an Electric Utility company receives a postal money order to pay an electric bill and the invoice number is recorded on the money order. The utility then returns this money order and states that they refuse to accept it. Is the electric bill then deemed satisfied under the law?

Comment: Since you are not the obligor, it would seem it is not satisfied.

Comment: Cicero, if what you state in the comment is your question then edit it to say that.  That is @user6726's point.  Rejecting a check from a third party is not the same thing as rejecting a money order from the debtor.

Comment: @MichaelHall A postal money order is a "check from a third party". When a person receives a check, there is no way to know who it is "from". A check simply has a bank id and account number. Who may or may not control that account is private information known only to the bank. The vendor has no way to know who owns a particular bank account.

Comment: The vendor absolutely has a way to know who owns a particular bank account, because as you state in the question, your company name is on the check!  And a money order is not a check, it is a money order.

Comment: @Cicero That's wrong too, a money order (and cashier's, official, and traveler's) has a from/remitter field. For one, the remitter has rights in the money and can also cash the money order, e.g. if they decide not to send it.

Comment: @user71659: Even if has such a field, often it can be left blank.

Comment: @ohwilleke: So per the UCC sections you linked, since checks are "a manner current in the course of ordinary business", it seems that the creditor must accept it unless they choose to demand payment in legal tender (i.e. currency).  So we could ask whether refusing the debtor's third-party check is in effect a demand for payment in legal tender, while possibly holding out the option that they could relent and accept something else (such as debtor's own check).

Comment: Setting aside the law, from the standpoint of practical business, a vendor refusing a third-party check doesn't seem "crazy" at all.  They have no way of knowing whether the alleged agent is actually authorized to sign checks for that company, and so the company check has a higher chance of being bounced as fraudulent.  Unlike bounces for non-sufficient funds, which happen within days, a bounce for fraud can happen weeks later.  Then the vendor is out the money unless they can track down the agent, who may have skipped town.  They have no recourse against the company.

Comment: @NateEldredge I haven't analyzed the issue at all due to lack of time. I hit a buzzword and a couple of citations without spelling them out.

Comment: I guess another issue is that although payment by a party's *own* check is certainly "a manner current in the ordinary course of business", it's not clear whether one could say the same about payment with *another* party's check.

Answer (score 1):

### it depends on the contract.

Let's say Alice has a contract with Bob, formulated as follows: Alice lends Bob 20 dollars and in return, Bob repays Alice 2 dollars a week for 11 weeks.

The contract does not have room for an early payment of any outstanding amount. It also has no room for Charly to pay for Bob's fees. So Alice does not **have** to accept Bob trying to pay off all the remaining amount at once, or Charly to pay for Bob's loan. She may, but nothing forces her to accept those alterations to the contract. She can insist on the term: Bob repays Alice 2 dollars a week for 11 weeks.

Now, Bob presents a check for 2 dollars that is signed by Charly. Does Alice have to accept it? No. Alice is entitled to a payment **from Bob**. The Check is a payment that goes from Charly to whoever cashes the check. Alice is not entitled to any payment from Charly. In fact, she might not even be allowed to cash the check legally.

Since Alice is entitled to the payment from Bob, Bob could cash the check from Charly and then write a check to Alice. Or Bob could do a money transfer to Alice. Or he could take the cash to Alice. But she does **not** need to accept a check that is not a payment *by Bob*. Though, nothing forces her to accept checks to begin with, if her terms of service exclude payment by check.

Comment: But what if there’s no written contract that goes into such detail?  The question seems to be a basic “product X at price Y” transaction, with just a minor wrinkle…

Answer (score 1):

### A contract may restrict the manner of payment

All contracts implicitly limit payment to the currency in which they are denominated. So, for a contract denominated in USD, payment in EUR or CAD or Bitcoin or poppy seeds may be refused.

A contract may restrict payment by excluding some forms (e.g. no checks or no cash) or by specifically nominating a form (e.g. payment will be by electronic funds transfer). Such terms are binding and other types of payment may be refused.

If the contract is silent then the recipient may reasonably limit the types of payment they will accept. In countries where there is a legal tender law (e.g. the
[USA](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/31/5103)), legal tender must be accepted unless the contract excludes it. Note that not all jurisdictions have legal tenet laws; Scotland for example and, in England and Wales, it is limited to banknotes issued by the Bank of England - notes from Scottish banks are not legal tender even though they are in GBP.

Offering payment of a debt in legal tender discharges it whether or not it is accepted - again, unless the contract excludes that method of payment.

### TL;DR

The creditor is not obliged to accept that (or any other) check. You still owe the money.

Answer (score 0):

ohwilleke was nice enough to answer this question in the comments, so I will just expand on what he wrote. Presenting a negotiable instrument does extinguish the debt if the creditor refuses it. Here is the quote from the UCC:

> 2016 New Hampshire Revised Statutes
> Title XXXIV-A - UNIFORM COMMERCIAL CODE
> Chapter 382-A - UNIFORM COMMERCIAL CODE
> Section 382-A:3-603 - Tender of Payment.
> Universal Citation: NH Rev Stat § 382-A:3-603 (2016)
>
> 382-A:3-603 Tender of Payment.
> (b) If tender of payment of an obligation to pay an instrument is made to a person entitled to enforce the instrument and the tender is
> refused, there is discharge, to the extent of the amount of the
> tender, of the obligation of an indorser or accommodation party having
> a right of recourse with respect to the obligation to which the tender
> relates.

Comment: I don't think your summary is accurate.  "Instrument" here refers to something like a promissory note that is being "enforced" (i.e. collected on).  To discharge that obligation, you have to make "tender of payment", which is defined in ohwilleke's link as needing to be made in "any means or in any manner current in the ordinary course of business".

Comment: Allowing the debt to be discharged by presenting any negotiable instrument would be absurd (and btw the word "negotiable" is nowhere in the quote).  "[Negotiable instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negotiable_instrument)" includes not only checks but also promissory notes, such as an IOU from your deadbeat Uncle Harry.  It's "negotiable" in the sense that you can sign it over to someone else, and now they are the one who can (try to) collect from Uncle Harry, but that doesn't mean it's actually worth anything like its face value.

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, by "negotiable instrument" I am meaning "tender of payment" such as a company check or bank check or money order or US Treasury note.

Comment: Okay, but what I'm saying is that "negotiable instrument" and "tender of payment" mean very different things and should not be conflated.  It's confusing to use a technical term that has an established technical meaning, and then say that by it you mean something else entirely.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, their refusal to accept your check frees you from any obligation to pay for this debt.  You don’t owe them any money and they have no claim against you.

However, the agent who bought these goods is still on the hook because they are the one who entered into a purchase agreement with the vendor.

They have a right to do business with others as they choose, and they have chosen to not do business with you or the company you represent.  Your relationship with the agent is of no interest or concern to them.